(SOLVED) System.NotSupportedException and System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException while implementing SkiaSharp in .net Maui
Hello i was implementing skiasharp on .net 8.0 Maui and i constantly receive System.NotSupportedException and System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException. I am trying to understand why i keep receiving these errors. I started a new project. Added the Nuget package. Added UseSkiaSharp() to the builder. Added the required using statement. Added the namespace to the xaml file. Added a JSON from Lottie. ran the program and it crashes.
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls.Hosting;

namespace MauiApp1
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseSkiaSharp()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage"
             xmlns:skia="clr-namespace:SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Controls;assembly=SkiaSharp.Extended.UI">

    <ScrollView>
        <skia:SKLottieView
            Source="Free.json"/>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui" Version="3.0.0-preview.7" />
    </ItemGroup>

I followed the implementation from this article: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/lottie-animations-in-net-maui2/
and after it didn't work i looked up how others implemented it and they did it as in the above article. If i comment out the lines below:
<skia:SKLottieView             
    Source="Free.json"/>   

the program will start (everything but the Skia Implementation is default MAUI). So im certain its due to implementing Skia. Though id like to know why, and if possible how to fix the issue.
Edit: Adding stack trace. In order to get the stack trace i needed to put a break point in the MainPage code behind before initializing the page. So i don't know if it will be of use. If i try and get the stack trace without the breakpoint then i cant cause the program breaks and locks m e out of vs2022 till i close everything. Below are the folllowing snips:
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
If i run the program normally then i receive this popup:
enter image description here
And the program closes before i can get the stack trace.

I can reproduce this issue. This issue happens on Windows, which may relate to [BUG] .net maui SkiaSharp crashe. The SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui NuGet depends on SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls NuGet, so it also crashes. Good news is the issue has been fixed in the latest version.
The workaround is to manually install the latest SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls NuGet, and it works.
Here is the package I've installed
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Extended.UI.Maui" Version="3.0.0-preview.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls" Version="3.0.0-preview.5.4" />

Here is the snippet of code
<skia:SKLottieView  WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="300" Source="dotnetbot.json" RepeatCount="-1" />

Here is the result

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you so very much! Your solution worked :D  (i did need to still download the SkiaSharp and SkiaSharp.View.Maui.Core)!!! It also taught me to look at the dependency tree when downloading nuget packages :D

An interesting discovery i made, if you try to Dependancy Inject the View the lottie file is in, you will get an error:
Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException' in Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.dll.
Have not found the workaround other than just calling the view in normally

try to Dependancy Inject the View the lottie file is in  Please share the relevant code how you do it,

Ill share the code when i get home. But there is no need to try and solve the issue. this was just somethng interesting i noticed and wanted to share :)

Okay, glad my answer helps! And just let me know if you have any question!
